# .NET How to set thread name of a process that I programmatically start

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio

My VB.NET app programmatically starts a process to run a script (Julia).
 I assume one of the threads shown in the VS Threads window is the thread for this process.
I want to name the thread so I can spot it in the Threads box:

[image]

I start the process with this code:

```
Dim Julia_RF_process As New ProcessStartInfo()
Julia_RF_process.WorkingDirectory = RF_PROCESS_FILEPATH
Julia_RF_process.FileName = "rundirect.exe"
Julia_RF_process.Arguments = RF_DETECT_PATHNAME
Process.Start( Julia_RF_process )
```

How can I set its thread name, so I can easily identify it in my Visual Studio > Threads pane?

Comment: Process does not start a new Thread. It starts a new App Instance. There is a huge difference between Multithreading via Multiple App Domains and Multithreading by starting new threads from the same App Domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your process in a new thread and name that:

```
Dim t = New Thread(Function()
                       Dim process = Process.Start("rundirect.exe")
                       process.WaitForExit()
                   End Function)
t.Name = "MyThtread"
t.Start()

Do other stuff...

t.Join()
```

Of course threads and processes are different things. .Net *Process* API lets you start and manage OS processes. Whereas *Thread* API lets you create and manage threads in your own process (that is a console app for example). Start your program (preferably make it a simple console app first) and try to see the processes created in something like [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), which is a great tool by the way.

Hope that helps